# SQL Join Query in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, nested

I have a table storing Agents details, which looks as follows:

[image: AgentTable]

In another table, I have Tax Bracket information which looks as follows:

[image: TaxTable]

I need to execute a query on the 2 tables, in which I display the agent's name, the total amount of tax which they pay based on the tax bracket into which they fall and their salary, their supervisor's name and the amount of tax that the supervisor pays also, based on the tax bracket into which they fall and their salary. This purpose of the query is to show that the supervisors are paying a much larger amount in tax than their subordinates, due to the percentages of the tax brackets.

Here is the query I have formulated so far:

```
Select A.AgentName AS AgentName,
 ((A.Salary)*(Select S.PlusPercentage FROM TaxBracket AS S WHERE A.Salary >=S.FromEarnings AND A.Salary <= S.ToEarnings) + S.BasicTax)  AS "Tax Paid By Agent" ,
B.AgentName AS "Supervisor", 
((B.Salary)*(Select T.PlusPercentage FROM TaxBracket AS T WHERE A.Salary >=T.FromEarnings AND A.Salary <= T.ToEarnings) + T.BasicTax)  AS "Tax Paid By Supervisor" ,
FROM Agent AS 'A', TaxBracket AS 'S', Agent AS 'B', TaxBracket AS 'T'
WHERE A.Supervisor = B.AgentNo
AND A.Commission IS NULL,
ORDER BY A.AgentName DESC
```

I get an error which states "The select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

I'm not sure of where this error is occurring though, can anyone please help?

Comment: First thing that tracks my attention is that you are quoting your table aliases, like 'A'. Is this necessary in Access (no idea). Because in sql this will not work. Have you tried if it works when you are removing this quotes?

Comment: @Kevin I don't think it is necessary but it is valid in MS Access

Comment: You also have a comma after your last field in the SELECT clause, ... AS "Tax Paid By Supervisor" , FROM. Again in sql this is not correct. I also see another comma just in front of your ORDER BY clause. Maybe you can remove those and try again.

Comment: Can you upload a sample data to quickly reply your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your sql:

There is comma at the end of your SELECT (remove the comma)

```
T.BasicTax)  AS "Tax Paid By Supervisor" ,
FROM
```

There is a comma at the end of your FROM (remove the comma)

```
AND A.Commission IS NULL,
ORDER BY
```

Your aliases for the tables should not be wrapped (remove the apostrophes)

```
Agent AS 'A', TaxBracket AS 'S', Agent AS 'B', TaxBracket AS 'T'
```

For field names, use square brackets (remove quotes, replace with '[' and ']')

```
AS "Tax Paid By Agent",
AS [Tax Paid By Agent],
```

fixed:

```
SELECT
    A.AgentName AS AgentName,
    (
        (A.Salary) * (
            SELECT
                S.PlusPercentage
            FROM
                TaxBracket AS S
            WHERE
                A.Salary >= S.FromEarnings
            AND A.Salary <= S.ToEarnings
        ) + S.BasicTax
    ) AS [Tax Paid By Agent],
    B.AgentName AS [Supervisor],
    (
        (B.Salary) * (
            SELECT
                T.PlusPercentage
            FROM
                TaxBracket AS T
            WHERE
                A.Salary >= T.FromEarnings
            AND A.Salary <= T.ToEarnings
        ) + T.BasicTax
    ) AS [Tax Paid By Supervisor]
FROM
    Agent AS A,
    TaxBracket AS S,
    Agent AS B,
    TaxBracket AS T
WHERE
    A.Supervisor = B.AgentNo
    AND A.Commission IS NULL
ORDER BY
    A.AgentName DESC
```

If you want something a bit simpler, perhaps try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    a.AgentName,
    a.Salary,
    (SELECT a.Salary*([PlusPercentage])+t.BasicTax AS tax FROM TaxBracket AS t WHERE t.FromEarnings<=a.Salary AND t.ToEarnings>=a.Salary;) AS aTax,
    s.AgentName AS Supervisor,
    s.Salary,
    (SELECT s.Salary*([PlusPercentage])+t.BasicTax AS tax FROM TaxBracket AS t WHERE t.FromEarnings<=s.Salary AND t.ToEarnings>=s.Salary;) AS sTax
FROM Agent AS a LEFT JOIN Agent AS s ON a.Supervisor = s.AgentNo;
```